# Batch file if statment wont excute set command

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set chk=tru
set final=c:\users\user1\desktop
set var=c:\users\user1\desktop
    for %%s in (%final%) do (
        echo %%s
        echo %var%
        if %var%==%%s set chk=false
        echo %chk%
    )
```

the two strings are the same but the if statment wont excute the set command 
and change the chk variable. can someone please help?
im new to batch scripting and i dont understand why this dosent work.
i think its a technical matter i just dont know about

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

in for loop use exclamation marks to reference variable. try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set chk=tru
set final=c:\users\user1\desktop
set var=c:\users\user1\desktop
    for %%s in (%final%) do (
        echo %%s
        echo %var%
        if {%var%}=={%%s} set chk=false
        echo !chk!
    )
```

and read about [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the value of chk in the loop itself the changes made gets reflected back only in the next iteration. Thus you **need to use ! instead of %** to see the change immediately.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set chk=tru
set final=c:\users\user1\desktop
set var=c:\users\user1\desktop
    for %%s in (%final%) do (
        echo %%s
        echo %var%
        if %var%==%%s set chk=false
        echo !chk!
    )
```